# golang CIDR prefix notation to IP address/subnet mask (dot-decimal)

Tags: go, cidr

Is there something similar to '***npm netmask***' in golang ? I need to convert i.e. 10.0.0.0/**8** to 10.0.0.0/**255.0.0.0** so basically netmask in CIDR format to dot-decimal.

```
var Netmask = require('netmask').Netmask
var block = new Netmask('10.0.0.0/8');
block.mask; // 255.0.0.0
```

I can't find it in /golang.org/src/net/ip.go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The go standard library does not have a function to create that representation. That being said, it is not difficult to do yourself:

https://play.golang.org/p/XT_UXoy6ra

```
func main() {
    _, ipv4Net, err := net.ParseCIDR("10.0.0.0/8")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(ipv4MaskString(ipv4Net.Mask))
}

func ipv4MaskString(m []byte) string {
    if len(m) != 4 {
        panic("ipv4Mask: len must be 4 bytes")
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", m[0], m[1], m[2], m[3])
}
```

Keep in mind this format only works for ipv4 masks. If you were to pass an ipv6 mask, this would panic.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the golang standard library to get the dot representation like so:

```
ipaddr, ipv4Net, err := net.ParseCIDR("10.0.0.0/8")
// handle error
fmt.Println(net.IP(ipv4Net.Mask).String())
```

This works because both the mask and the IP is backed by a `[]byte` slice (see the stdlib source), so you can convert between them by casting directly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works with both IPv4 and IPv6 using the [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/).  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
func main() {
    convert("10.0.0.0/8")
    convert("10::/64")
}

func convert(cidrStr string) {
    cidr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(cidrStr).GetAddress()
    fmt.Println(cidr.GetNetworkMask())
}
```

Output:

```
255.0.0.0
ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
```